# How can I display the current value from a chart?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am new to React and I work on a small project basically, I have a chart and I just want to display the current value from the chart.

For example, I have a chart with 4 random values:[5,2,5,1], so I want to have displayed the current value below the chart like first is 5, second is 2 and so on.
Here is my part of code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    addPoint = (point) => {
        currentData = this.state.options.series[0].data
        this.setState({
            options: {
                series: [
                    { data: [...currentData, point]}
                ]
            }
        });
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.internalChart = undefined;
        this.dataStream = new DataStream();
        this.dataStream.setUpdateCallback(this.addPoint);

        this.state = {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    events: {
                        load: function () {
                        }
                    }
                },

                time: {
                    useUTC: false
                },

                rangeSelector: {
                    buttons: [{
                        count: 1,
                        type: 'minute',
                        text: '1M'
                    }, {
                        count: 5,
                        type: 'minute',
                        text: '5M'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
                    inputEnabled: false,
                    selected: 2
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Live random data'
                },

                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Random data',
                    data: [[(new Date()).getTime(), 0]]
                }]
            }
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <HighchartsReact
                constructorType={"stockChart"}
                highcharts={Highcharts}
                options={this.state.options}
                /> 
        );
    }}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on the online editor? Here is my attempt: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-jvd4o and I think that you should be able to display point values by using the dataLabels feature: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels

Answer (score 0):

Based on your snippet code, try to make random method by using function

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max))
```

And then assign the options to HighchartsReact,

Full code on sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-dream-0lzj1